# How do I derive $\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+1/x)^x,\quad x\in\mathbb{R}$ from $\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^n=e,\quad n\in\mathbb{N}$?

Tags: limits-without-lhopital

> How do I derive
>   $$\lim_{x\to\infty}(1+1/x)^x,\quad x\in\mathbb{R}\tag{1}$$
>   from
>   $$\lim_{n\to\infty}(1+1/n)^n=e,\quad n\in\mathbb{N}\tag{2}$$
>   ?

Note:

- Without calculus (continuity, derivative, aso.).
- (2) is only an idea, every method using limit, Cauchy, aso is good.

Comment: Why no calculus? It's so easy to prove that $(1+1/x)^x$ is monotonous that way, which immediately would give you the result.

Comment: because it has not yet been introduced in the book at the point of the exercise

Comment: tnx for the downvote

Comment: That weren't me, by the way. I hope whoever downvoted tells us why. Odds are it's a knee-jerk reaction to seing your question without any of your own work, but it would've been decent of them to leave a comment explaining that. Some people think new users understand things like that automatically.

Comment: @Arthur: I never thought you could be

Comment: Related http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1933369/how-do-i-prove-this-limit

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: say $n \le x \le n+1$ ($x$ large). 
Then $$ \left ( 1 +{1\over x }\right )^x \le \left( 1 + {1\over n}\right)^{n+1}.$$
Do something similar to bound the term to limit below, and use the squeeze theorem.