# How do I prove this limit?

Tags: calculus, limits

I've been looking at some proofs of derivatives of functions and the teacher who made it used this in his proof:

$$
\lim_{u \to 0}((1+u)^{\frac{1}{u}})=e\
$$

I can see that this is true by substituting small values for *u* but **why is this true and how do I prove it?**

I would thank you if you could explain on more of a basic level, since I am quite a beginner here :)

Thanks in advance!

PS Sorry for my sloppy Enlgish

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far, and what are you stuck on? This limit is often taken to be the definition of $e$ (or in the equivalent form with $u\to\infty$, though it's still necessary to prove its convergence.

Comment: And, [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/136784/why-lim-limits-n-to-infty-left1-frac1n-rightn-doesnt-evaluate-to). And finally, [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/35486/proof-that-this-limit-equals-ea).

Comment: This is often used as an alternative definition of $e$

Comment: How are you defining $e$?  One definition of $e$ is the number such that $$\int_1^e \frac{1}{x}\,dx=1$$while another is $$e=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{n!}$$an yet a third is $$e=\lim_{n\to \infty}\left(1+\frac1n\right)^n$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the continuity of $\ln(x)$ and by setting the limit equal to $L\in\Bbb R$ we have:
$$\begin{align}\lim_{u\to 0}(1+u)^{\frac{1}{u}}&=L\\\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{1}{u}\ln(1+u)&=\ln(L)\\\lim_{u\to 0}\frac{1}{1+u}&=\ln(L)\\1&=\ln(L)\\L&=e\end{align}$$
Note that L'Hopital's rule was used on line 3.

Comment: This seems to be a circular argument.  How are you defining the logarithm function?  And what is the definition of $e$ you're using here?

Comment: Define the natural logarithm as the integral of the standard hyperbola

Comment: First, one needs to show that the limit of interest exists.

Comment: That's where I assumed the limit is equal to L where L is some arbitrary place holder, and then we show L is finite.

Comment: This isn't quite rigorous, but could easily have been made so.

Comment: Define $\log(x)$ as $\log(x)=\int_1^x \frac{1}{t}\,dt$, $x>0$, and $e$ as the number such that $\log(e)=1$.  It is easy to show that the logarithm is continuous for $x>0$ and satisfies $\log(x^n)=n\log(x)$.  Then, we have $$\log((1+u)^{1/u}) =\frac1u \int_{1}^{1+u}\frac{1}{t}\,dt\tag 1$$The MVT shows that the limit of $(1)$ is $1$.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:**

Compute the limit of the logarithm of the expression.